# Error in reading JSON. Only assigns null values

Tags: java, arrays, json, data-structures

I'm trying to open a JSON file and save its contents into an Object. However the object always has null contents after opening the JSON file. Here's the code

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Ciudad {
    private List<Colonia> colonias;
    private List<Enlace> enlaces;
    private List<Central> centrales;

    public List<Colonia> getColonias() {
        return colonias;
    }

    public List<Enlace> getEnlaces() {
        return enlaces;
    }

    public List<Central> getCentrales() {
        return centrales;
    }

    public static class Colonia {
        private String nombre;
        private long coordenadaX;
        private long coordenadaY;

        public Colonia(String nombre, long coordenadaX, long coordenadaY) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.coordenadaX = coordenadaX;
            this.coordenadaY = coordenadaY;
        }

        public String getNombre() {
            return nombre;
        }

        public long getCoordenadaX() {
            return coordenadaX;
        }

        public long getCoordenadaY() {
            return coordenadaY;
        }
    }

    public static class Enlace {
        private String coloniaInicial;
        private String coloniaFinal;
        private long distancia;
        private long capacidad;

        public Enlace(String coloniaInicial, String coloniaFinal, long distancia, long capacidad) {
            this.coloniaInicial = coloniaInicial;
            this.coloniaFinal = coloniaFinal;
            this.distancia = distancia;
            this.capacidad = capacidad;
        }

        public String getColoniaInicial() {
            return coloniaInicial;
        }

        public String getColoniaFinal() {
            return coloniaFinal;
        }

        public long getDistancia() {
            return distancia;
        }

        public long getCapacidad() {
            return capacidad;
        }
    }

    public static class Central {
        private long x;
        private long y;

        public Central(long x, long y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public long getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public long getY() {
            return y;
        }
    }

    public static Ciudad cargarCiudadDesdeJSON(String rutaArchivo) {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(rutaArchivo))) {
            // Parsear el archivo JSON
            Object obj = parser.parse(reader);
            JSONObject ciudadJSON = (JSONObject) obj;

            Ciudad ciudad = new Ciudad();
            ciudad.colonias = cargarColoniasDesdeJSON((JSONArray) ciudadJSON.get("colonias"));
            ciudad.enlaces = cargarEnlacesDesdeJSON((JSONArray) ciudadJSON.get("enlaces"));
            ciudad.centrales = cargarCentralesDesdeJSON((JSONArray) ciudadJSON.get("centrales"));

            return ciudad;
        } catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static List<Colonia> cargarColoniasDesdeJSON(JSONArray coloniasJSON) {
        List<Colonia> colonias = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Object coloniaObj : coloniasJSON) {
            JSONObject coloniaJSON = (JSONObject) coloniaObj;
            String nombre = (String) coloniaJSON.get("nombre");
            long coordenadaX = (Long) coloniaJSON.get("coordenadaX");
            long coordenadaY = (Long) coloniaJSON.get("coordenadaY");

            Colonia colonia = new Colonia(nombre, coordenadaX, coordenadaY);
            colonias.add(colonia);
        }

        return colonias;
    }

    private static List<Enlace> cargarEnlacesDesdeJSON(JSONArray enlacesJSON) {
        List<Enlace> enlaces = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Object enlaceObj : enlacesJSON) {
            JSONObject enlaceJSON = (JSONObject) enlaceObj;
            String coloniaInicial = (String) enlaceJSON.get("coloniaInicial");
            String coloniaFinal = (String) enlaceJSON.get("coloniaFinal");
            long distancia = (Long) enlaceJSON.get("distancia");
            long capacidad = (Long) enlaceJSON.get("capacidad");

            Enlace enlace = new Enlace(coloniaInicial, coloniaFinal, distancia, capacidad);
            enlaces.add(enlace);
        }

        return enlaces;
    }

    private static List<Central> cargarCentralesDesdeJSON(JSONArray centralesJSON) {
        List<Central> centrales = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Object centralObj : centralesJSON) {
            JSONObject centralJSON = (JSONObject) centralObj;
            long coordenadaX = (Long) centralJSON.get("x");
            long coordenadaY = (Long) centralJSON.get("y");

            Central central = new Central(coordenadaX, coordenadaY);
            centrales.add(central);
        }

        return centrales;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String rutaArchivo = "C:\\Users\\emili\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\Java\\A01770892_ActInt2\\A01770892_ActInt2\\Version2\\Grafo.json";
        Ciudad ciudad = cargarCiudadDesdeJSON(rutaArchivo);

        if (ciudad != null) {
            System.out.println("Colonias:");
            for (Colonia colonia : ciudad.getColonias()) {
                System.out.println("Nombre: " + colonia.getNombre() +
                        ", CoordenadaX: " + colonia.getCoordenadaX() +
                        ", CoordenadaY: " + colonia.getCoordenadaY());
            }

            System.out.println("\nEnlaces:");
            for (Enlace enlace : ciudad.getEnlaces()) {
                System.out.println("Colonia Inicial: " + enlace.getColoniaInicial() +
                        ", Colonia Final: " + enlace.getColoniaFinal() +
                        ", Distancia: " + enlace.getDistancia() +
                        ", Capacidad: " + enlace.getCapacidad());
            }

            System.out.println("\nCentrales:");
            for (Central central : ciudad.getCentrales()) {
                System.out.println("X: " + central.getX() + ", Y: " + central.getY());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's how the JSON file looks like

```
{
  "ciudad": {
    "colonias": [
      {
        "nombre": "C1",
        "coordenadaX": "100",
        "coordenadaY": 25
      },
      {
        "nombre": "C2",
        "coordenadaX": "80",
        "coordenadaY": 250
      },
      {
        "nombre": "C3",
        "coordenadaX": "14",
        "coordenadaY": 125
      },
      {
        "nombre": "C4",
        "coordenadaX": "7",
        "coordenadaY": 25
      }
    ],
    "enlaces": [
      {
        "coloniaInicial": "C1",
        "coloniaFinal": "C2",
        "distancia": 16,
        "capacidad": 48
      },
      {
        "coloniaInicial": "C1",
        "coloniaFinal": "C3",
        "distancia": 45,
        "capacidad": 12
      },
      {
        "coloniaInicial": "C1",
        "coloniaFinal": "C4",
        "distancia": 32,
        "capacidad": 18
      },
      {
        "coloniaInicial": "C2",
        "coloniaFinal": "C1",
        "distancia": 16,
        "capacidad": 52
      },
      {
        "coloniaInicial": "C2",
        "coloniaFinal": "C3",
        "distancia": 18,
        "capacidad": 42
      },
      {
        "coloniaInicial": "C2",
        "coloniaFinal": "C4",
        "distancia": 21,
        "capacidad": 32
      },
      {
        "coloniaInicial": "C3",
        "coloniaFinal": "C1",
        "distancia": 45,
        "capacidad": 18
      },
      {
        "coloniaInicial": "C3",
        "coloniaFinal": "C2",
        "distancia": 18,
        "capacidad": 46
      },
      {
        "coloniaInicial": "C3",
        "coloniaFinal": "C4",
        "distancia": 7,
        "capacidad": 56
      },
      {
        "coloniaInicial": "C4",
        "coloniaFinal": "C1",
        "distancia": 45,
        "capacidad": 18
      },
      {
        "coloniaInicial": "C4",
        "coloniaFinal": "C2",
        "distancia": 18,
        "capacidad": 46
      },
      {
        "coloniaInicial": "C4",
        "coloniaFinal": "C3",
        "distancia": 7,
        "capacidad": 56
      }
    ],
    "centrales": [
      {
        "x": "200",
        "y": "500"
      },
      {
        "x": "300",
        "y": "100"
      },
      {
        "x": "450",
        "y": "150"
      },
      {
        "x": "450",
        "y": "150"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The data is supposed to be stored appropiately in the Object Ciudad (City). However it does not work properly.

Comment: I suggest using a debugger to step/walk through your code and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

There is a top level object named `ciudad` which you aren't accessing.

In your `cargarCiudadDesdeJSON` method, change

```
JSONObject ciudadJSON = (JSONObject) obj;
```

to

```
JSONObject ciudadJSON = (JSONObject) ((JSONObject) obj).get("ciudad");
```

Node: Additionally, there are a few type mismatch issues. You are expecting `colonias#coordenadaX`, `centrales#x`, `centrales#y` to be *long*, but they are string in the JSON. To fix it, update the type either in JSON or the Java model or do the type conversion in code.